Setting the User-Agent in a window.open request
I understand now that from @Gertjan Brouwer's comments in this discussion, what I want to do to change the User-Agent header is to issue the following sequence for an XMLHttpRequest, something like so:
open("GET",url);
setRequestHeader('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 17_5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Mobile/15E148');
send();

I further understand that the URL with attendant parameter data is not passed to the server until the send() is issued. Is that correct?
If so, then I have two questions, if I am to substitute an XMLHttpRequest for the existing code snippet below, in the hopes of being able to override the default browser User-Agent:
window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);


Does a window.open ultimately issue a send()?  If not, how is the window currently being populated by the server?

Is there a way for me to pass windowSize to the server using an XMLHttpRequest?


Thanks
Dan

BUMP.
I tried replacing the open.window with the code above, and got this message:
No route found for "GET /GET" (from "https://www.59plymouth.net/59forum/viewtopic.php?t=3470")
